# How to repalce datalist in DrawerItem after signin in android

Tags: java, android

I want to replace DrawerItem datalist after user logged in. I tried but its append not replace.. Can anyone help to resolve this scenerio.

In the below code, i want, its happen after this navigatetoSearchActivity() method.

Here my code:

MainActivity.java

```js
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        getScreenResolution();
        // validation();
        // IF NOT SIGNEDUP then start loginActivity, else searchActivity
        if (pref.getInt(getString(R.string.signedupflag), 0) == 0) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        } else {

        }

        UserAccount usr = new UserAccount();

        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        // mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        mRightDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.right_drawer);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        // First time app usage should check for the user login
        pref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //If user already logged in then get user name and show search screen
        if (pref.contains("name")) {
            String userName = pref.getString("name", "");
            // Add Drawer Item to dataList
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list - 0

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Balance", R.drawable.ic_balance)); // - 2

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile"));// adding a header to the list - 3
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Personal", R.drawable.ic_account));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Work", R.drawable.ic_work));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Address", R.drawable.ic_home));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Vehicle", R.drawable.ic_car));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Preference", R.drawable.ic_pref));

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
        } else { // Show the sign-up/login screen. Get Name, Email and Mobile
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true));
            //dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1

            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
            dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
        }

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


    }


public void navigatetoSearchActivity(){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
     
        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list - 0

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Wallet")); // adding a header to the list - 1
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Balance", R.drawable.ic_balance)); // - 2

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Profile"));// adding a header to the list - 3
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Personal", R.drawable.ic_account));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Work", R.drawable.ic_work));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Address", R.drawable.ic_home));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Vehicle", R.drawable.ic_car));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Preference", R.drawable.ic_pref));

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Other Option")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));
        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: [`ArrayAdapter.clear()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29).

Comment: Where i put this line in my coding

Comment: Just where you need to remove the existing entries before adding the new ones, i.e., as you said, "after this navigatetoSearchActivity() method". Make sure you `clear()` the `dataList` too, if you intend to re-use it.

Comment: I have one more doubt.. If i choose item in that drawer means its show that layout like that i want while clicking next button also...What i do

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand that question.